# pandas panel data update

Tags: python, panel-data, pandas

I am using panel datastructure in pandas for storing a 3d panel.

```
T=pd.Panel(data=np.zeros((n1,n2,n3)),items=n1_label, major_axis=n2_label, minor_axis=n3_label)
```

Later on, I am trying to update (increment) the values stored at individual locations inside a loop. Currently I am doing:

```
 u=T.get_value(n1_loop,n2_loop,n3_loop)
 T.set_value(n1_loop,n2_loop,n3_loop,u+1)
```

My question- is this the simplest way? Is there any other simpler way? The following dont work:

```
T[n1_loop,n2_loop,n3_loop] +=1
```

or

```
T[n1_loop,n2_loop,n3_loop] = T[n1_loop,n2_loop,n3_loop] +1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR***

```
T.update(T.loc[[n1_loop], [n2_loop], [n3_loop]].add(1))
```

---

The analogous exercise for a DataFrame would be to assign with `loc`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 5)), list('abcde'), list('ABCDE'), int)
df.loc['b':'d', list('AE')] += 1
df
```

[image]

---

Exact `pd.Panel` analog generates an Error

```
pn = pd.Panel(np.zeros((5, 5, 2)), list('abcde'), list('ABCDE'), list('XY'), int)
pn.loc['b':'d', list('AE'), ['X']] += 1
pn
```

> ```
> NotImplementedError: cannot set using an indexer with a Panel yet!
> ```

---

But we can still slice it

```
pn = pd.Panel(np.zeros((5, 5, 2)), list('abcde'), list('ABCDE'), list('XY'), int)
pn.loc['b':'d', list('AE'), ['X']]

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 1 (minor_axis)
Items axis: b to d
Major_axis axis: A to E
Minor_axis axis: X to X
```

---

And we can use the [`update` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.update.html)

```
pn.update(pn.loc['b':'d', list('AE'), ['X']].add(1))
```

Which we can see did stuff if we use the `to_frame` method

```
pn.to_frame().astype(int)
```

[image]

***OR***

```
pn.loc[:, :, 'X'].astype(int).T
```

[image]

---

***YOUR CASE***
This should work

```
T.update(T.loc[[n1_loop], [n2_loop], [n3_loop]].add(1))
```

Comment: somehow i get this error on trying 
T.update(T.loc[n1_loop, n2_loop, n3_loop].add(1))


AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: @dayum I assumed your loop variables were lists.

Comment: sorry probably should have mentioned this earlier, but n1_loop, n2_loop and n3_loop are all strings (referencing the indices along 3 axis)

Comment: @dayum if `n1_loop` is a string that is a single member of the `items` index and so on, then use `T.update(T.loc[[n1_loop], [n2_loop], [n3_loop]].add(1))`